# Set Values dont stick

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

Hello I am having a small issue. Below is a picture of my edit route for a story on my webpage. Groupwrites.com . When a user goes to edit a story, the input fields all have the information already set when the story was created, because of the value= " " field. This is great, because they can now make any edits/changes.

Problem is, for the category drop-down menu.For some reason the value does not stay when I go to edit a story. For example when I create a story , lets say its a blog and I choose Blog from the drop down. If I now go to edit that story, it defaults back to Fiction (first option) instead of saving the value. The issue is, most people go to edit content, and change the title for example, and don't notice that the category gets switched.

I am sure it is something small I am overlooking, thank you.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Edit
      <%= story.title %>
    </h1>
    <div style="width: 40%; margin: 40px auto;">
      <form action="/stories/<%= story._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="story[title]" value="<%= story.title %>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Image URL</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="story[image]" value="<%= story.image %>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Plot</label>
          <textarea name="story[description]" rows="15" cols="55" class="form-control"><%= story.description %></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Category</label>
          <select name="story[category]" class="form-control" value="<%= story.category %>">
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</option>
            <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
            <option value="Fan-fiction">Fan-fiction</option>
            <option value="Blog">Blog</option>
            <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
            <option value="Mystery">Mystery</option>
            <option value="Thriller">Thriller</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-large btn-success btn-block"> Publish </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your [mcve] as _text_ not an image.

Comment: Write here the code - it is always better than the image

Comment: My bad , changed the image for the code... Image seemed a lot easier to read imo lol.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Script, then just add

```
<script>
window.onload=function() { 
  document.querySelector("[name='story[category]']").value="<%‌​= story.category %>"
}
</script>
```

somewhere after the select

Answer (score 1):

You can set the selected attribute on the option:

```html
<select>
  <option selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Or in your case:

```
<option value="Fiction" selected="<%= story.category === 'Fiction' ? true : '' %>">
```

Or something like that (not too sure about the ejs syntax there)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This should be added to each option then right?

Comment: Jep or you could do something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878180/html-select-option-with-ejs

Comment: Hm tried to insert the selected attribute for each option and its now resorting to "Thriller" the last category, even though I clicked edit on a "Blog"

Comment: Hmm try an empty string instead of null as the non selected value (updated also the answer)