# Node.JS (Ejs template) - How to retain drop down values after submitting post request?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am using NodeJs and EJS as a template. I have a form that i do a post request and after this post request i filter the data and redirect to the same page with the filtered data that the user needs. 
I know how to get the values on server side of the form and pass it back to the new generated page.

How do i go to make the form show these values after post request and not reset.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 g-mb-50">
  <!-- Type -->
  <label class="g-font-weight-500 g-font-size-15 g-pl-30">Event Type</label>
  <select class="js-custom-select w-100 u-select-v2 u-shadow-v39 g-brd-main g-color-black g-bg-white text-left g-rounded-30 g-pl-30 g-py-12"
  data-placeholder="Type" data-open-icon="fa fa-angle-down"  name="constraints[eventType]" data-close-icon="fa fa-angle-up">                              
      <option class="" >All</option>
      <option class="" >Conference</option>
      <option class="" >Field Trip</option>
      <option class="" >ET Lab</option>
      <option class="" >Special Event</option>
  </select>
                                <!-- End Type -->

</div>
```

Comment: is cookie not an option?, or simply store the data on client before submitting

Comment: I already have the data, but how would i go to put it in the <select> so the box does not show the first option but the selected one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34878746