# Set select option value in ejs

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have a dropdown box in ejs where I want to set up a value for the drop down:

```
<select class="form-control" value='${stage[i]} name="stage[]">
  <option>Red</option> 
  <option>Yellow</option> 
  <option>Green</option> 
</select>
```

I want the value of the stage to be dynamically selected. As you can see I have set the value prperty

If I inspect my HTML, it shows that the value was supposed to be Green

```
    <select class="form-control" value="Green"> 
      <option>Red</option> 
      <option>Yellow</option> 
      <option>Green</option> 
   </select>
```

However, `Red` which is the first option is selected. How do I populate the value of the dropdown using ejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `selected`

```
<select class="form-control"> 
  <option>Red</option> 
  <option>Yellow</option> 
  <option selected>Green</option> 
</select>
```

For ejs you will have to use a condition statement to add selected to the correct option. Refer to [HTML select option with EJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878180/html-select-option-with-ejs) for more help.