# drop down list in a Form Clears value after submission by using node js

Tags: javascript

I am working on a form contains a drop down list and use node js. When I submit the form, if there is an error, the selected drop down list is back to unselected state. I know how to repopulate textbox input, so that it won't clear after submission. So, I used value="<%- deliveryInput%>, but it doesn't work in the same way for a drop down list. It seems that 'value' is not an attribute in select element. Is there any way to not clear the drop down list?

```
form.ejs

<label>DELIVERY TIME:</label>
<select name="delivery" value="<%- deliveryInput%>"> 
     <option value="">Select Days</option>
     <option value="1 Day">1 Day</option>
     <option value="2 Day">2 Day</option>
     <option value="3 Day">3 Day</option>
     <option value="4 Day">4 Day</option>
 </select>
```

```
index.js
delivery =req.body.delivery;
if (!errors.isEmpty() ||productQuantity){
            res.render('form',{
                errors:errors.array(),
                nameInput:name,
                emailInput:email,
                phoneInput:phone,
                addressInput:address,
                cityInput:city,
                postInput:post,
                provinceInput:province,
                product1Input:product1,
                product2Input:product2,
                product3Input:product3,
                deliveryInput:delivery,
                productError: "At leat buy one of the three products"
            })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML select option with EJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878180/html-select-option-with-ejs)